# How to concatenate a signal to achieve a desired property through a for loop?

Tags: concatenation, verilog, system-verilog

I have a signal named `signal`, and this is the definition of `signal`:

```
signal = |{`PS.iptile0.psst0.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile0.psst1.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile0.psst2.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile0.psst3.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile1.psst0.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile1.psst1.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile1.psst2.cols1.active_signal,
           `PS.iptile1.psst3.cols1.active_signal};
```

What I'm trying to do is achieve this property through a `for` loop.
This is my current code:

```
logic signal
logic [TILE*PARTS-1:0] signal_new;

generate
  for (genvar i = 0; i < TILE; i++) begin
    for (genvar j = 0; j < PARTS; j++) begin
        assign signal_new[i*PARTS+j] = {`PS.iptile${i}.psst${j}.cols1.active_signal};
    end
  end
endgenerate
signal = | {signal_new};
```

However, it is showing this syntax error:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
token is '.'
line: assign signal_new[i*PARTS+j] = {`PS.iptile${i}.psst${j}.cols1.active_signal};
```

From my understanding, this is because `signal_new` I'm trying to concatenate using `.`, but we can only concatenate a string not a logic.
Is there any way I can solve this?

Note:
I want:

```
`PS.iptile0.psst0.cols1.active_signal
```

to be like this and not like this:

```
`PS.iptile[0].psst[0].cols1.active_signal
```

That's why I can't use:

```
{`PS.iptile[i].psst[j].cols1.active_signal};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve what you want given your current design hierarchy.  Under your top module (`` `PS ``), you have 2 unrelated instances: `iptile0` and `iptile1`.  You gave the instances static names.

If you had created an **array** of instances (`iptile [1:0]`, for example), then you could have used a `generate` `for` loop to create your `signal_new`.  You would have also had to create an instance array of `psst` as well.  Then, your assignment would look something like:

```
assign signal_new[i*PARTS+j] = `PS.iptile[i].psst[j].cols1.active_signal;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.6 *Hierarchical names*:

> Names in a hierarchical path name that refer to **instance arrays** or
> **loop generate blocks** may be followed immediately by a constant
> expression in square brackets. This expression selects a particular
> instance of the array and is, therefore, called an instance select.
> The expression shall evaluate to one of the legal index values of the
> array.